# Does Pascal's Law hold true in this scenario?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

In the attached image, it has been told that the pressure at point A is equal to the pressure at point B(both at the same height).

**My question:** Can this be justified using Pascal's Law? Whether yes or no, how is it justified?

To clarify, the outline represents the  boundary of the container which is completely filled to the top by the liquid (the top slanted surface **does not represent the meniscus**).

[image]

Comment: Pascals law is about a change of pressure (in time), so it has nothing to do with fluid-statics, does it?

Comment: @Paul: Pascal's Law is hydrostatics. It also applies in dynamic conditions.

Comment: A liquid's meniscus is ALWAYS horizontal. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Gert I just looked at some older questions regarding that Law and it seems like the version on Wikipedia is not the one generally being meant. So nevermind.

Comment: @Gert I guess he means a filled, closed container, s.t. there is no meniscus.

Comment: Made the necessary edit. I only know about Pascal's Law in the hydrostatic situation(I'm fresh out of high school). I've made the necessary edit to clarify the other aspects

Comment: The fact that the top of the cylinder is slanted does not produce a different pressure at "A" vs. "B".  The pressure at both points will be $\rho g h_2$.

Comment: I seek a detailed explanation for why that is so. How is the pressure at A equal to the pressure at B, when the height of liquid columns is not equal at both the points?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the liquid to stay like that, it has to be held in place by a container on top (or some other forces), or else $h_1$ and $h_2$ would be the same because the water would level out.

Lets assume that the top of the water column on point $B$ is at atmospheric pressure.  For things to remain balanced, the pressure at the top of column $A$ has to be *above* atmospheric pressure.  Even though there's no water directly above it, for things to remain in balance, the water at the top of column $A$ has to be at the same pressure as the water in column $B$ at that same elevation, or else the higher pressure water could push it out of the way.

Essentially, the water at the top of column $A$ has some additional pressure, and actually would be pushing on the top of the container.  This additional pressure on the top of column $A$ is easy to calculate in this case, it would just be $p_{top A} = \rho g (h_2 - h_1)$.  This would mean the pressure at the *bottom* of column a is $$p_{bottom A} = p_{top A} + \rho g h_1 = \rho g (h_2 - h_1) + \rho g h_1 = \rho g h_2$$

[image: bad diagram of the pressures]
 (Sorry I mixed up $h_1$ and $h_2$ in this drawing)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have ignored the pressure applied by the top slanted surface on the water (in other words, pressure due to the normal force exerted by the top surface on the liquid). This extra pressure due to the top surface varies such that the pressure at any two points, at the same height (in your case $A$ and $B$), in the liquid will always be the same. And thus the Pascal's law holds true. In general, whenever you see an irregularly shaped container, there must be some pressure involved due to the contact/normal forces which would then add up to liquid's pressure such that the Pascal's law always holds true. In fact you can even find the pressure exerted by the walls of the container using Pascal's law and balancing the forces on the liquid.

Comment: So basically to ensure static situation, the forces have to be balanced out regardless of the geometry of the container?

Comment: Yes! In short, the forces will have to adjust such that Pascal's law is obeyed!